# c++ literal array notation

Tags: c++, qt

Hello i want to do a one line declaration i am using QT creator for my Quiz project, i want to pass it via literal array notation(JS) is there any other way declaring it in a one line declaration.

i would like to construct it like this:

```
Card c = new Card("Question?", 2, (Answer[]){ "answer 1", 1, "answer 2", 2, "answer 3", 3} );
```

Here's my class:

```
class Answer{
private:
    qint8 id;
    QString answer;

public:
    Answer(QString nAnswer, qint8 nId);
    QString getAnswer();
    qint8 getId();

};

class Card
{
private:
    QString question;
    QVector<Answer> answers;
    qint8 solutionId;

public:
    Card(QString nQuestion, qint8 nSolutionId, Answer[] );
    QString getQuestion();
    QVector<Answer> getAnswers();
    // void setSolutionId(qint8 nSolutionId);

};

Answer::Answer(QString nAnswer, qint8 nId)
{
    answer = nAnswer;
    id = nId;
}


Card::Card(QString nQuestion, qint8 nSolutionId, Answer nAnswers[])
{
    question = nQuestion;
    solutionId = nSolutionId;
}
```

Comment: Would the syntax `Card("Question?", 2, { {"answer 1", 1}, {"answer 2", 2}, {"answer 3", 3} } )` be acceptable?

Comment: i get the following error: `/home/marvin/quizDemo/main.cpp:10: Fehler: no matching function for call to ‘Card::Card(const char [10], int, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   10 |     Card("Question?", 2, { { 1, "answer 1"}, {2, "answer 2" }, {3,"answer 3"} } );
      |                                                                                 ^`

Comment: That's because your code needs some more changes.  I was just asking if you'd be okay with that construct because if you are I can show you what to change to allow that syntax to work.

Comment: yes im fine with it.

Comment: Change your constructor to accept `QVector<Answer>` instead of `Answer[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use

```
Card c = Card("Question?", 2, { {"answer 1", 1}, {"answer 2", 2}, {"answer 3", 3} } );
```

you need to change your

```
Card(QString nQuestion, qint8 nSolutionId, Answer[] );
```

constructor to take a `QVector<Answer>` instead of a `Answer[]`.  That would look like

```
Card(QString nQuestion, qint8 nSolutionId, QVector<Answer> nAnswers );

//...

Card(QString nQuestion, qint8 nSolutionId, QVector<Answer> nAnswers ) :
    question(nQuestion),
    answers(nAnswers),
    solutionId(nSolutionId)     
{}
```

The reason this works is because `QVector<T>` has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list<T>` so

```
{ {"answer 1", 1}, {"answer 2", 2}, {"answer 3", 3} }
```

will get converted into a `std::initializer_list<Answer>` to be used to initialize `answers`.